# Need a loop device for pam_mount

Tags: pam, pam-mount

I set up `pam_mount` to automatically mount a disk image on login, the image contains a `luks2` encrypted filesystem, very similar to [the example in the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pam_mount#LUKS_volumes).

My use case requires a loop device to be present at login time, otherwise the mount command will fail. On my OS (Arch), there are no loop devices present, they need to be created on-demand.

I came up with a systemd-service which just executes `losetup -f` and quits. That service solves the problem when started `After=local-fs.target` but is not ideal.

Are there other ways to create a loop device on boot ?

I can't use the `fstab` with type `loop`, as the login passphrase is needed for decryption.

I don't think `pam_mount` can be configured to execute arbitrary commands (just the command `losetup -f`) before it executes the mount command.

`pam_exec` looks like it's able to run `losetup -f`, I don't know whether it's supposed to be used for that.

Any thoughts ?